# How to update existing entities with JpaItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I'm using `spring-batch` jobs to persist content of a large `csv` file to a database.
`JpaItemWriter` is used for persistence, which is fine so far.

But now I'd like first to check if an entity already exists in the database (by `id` - the id field in csv and in database are equal), and in case just update the entity instead.

How could this be done?

Comment: JpaItemWriter use em.merge(T). If you use a composite key you could perform an update without modifies. Else I think that you can create a class that extends JpaItemWriter to make a custom update.

Comment: which DB are using most database supports upsert statement

Comment: I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to do this, the best I came up with was having my custom FieldSetMapper (used by the FlatFileItemReader) load the item from the database (or create a new instance of it doesn't exist) and then setting the properties based on the input. Since JpaItemWriter uses .merge, it will write the entity by updating if it was loaded from the database and insert if it was a new entity.

I also needed to have it run with a batch size of 1, to ensure that if there were duplicates in my input (which I did have), it would actually go one row at a time and insert or update for each one and not try to insert them all at once causing key problems.

As you might imagine, all this worked a *lot* slower than I would have liked. It queries the database for each and every row, and then does the corresponding update or insert. But as for my case it was for a monthly overnight batch process, it was good enough for our needs, even if it took many hours to run.